# Display Message when taking wrong direction from a specific destination

Tags: direction

In my app  I want to reach a specific destination from my current position and I'd like to inform me  with a message, an alert,... if I take wrong direction from the destination

Comment: What language? What framework or library? Edit your question and add more details.

Comment: i have built an adroid app and in my google map displayed my current location and a specific proximity alert. I want an alert to be visible when i get wrong direction from my destination

Comment: I've given you an answer that should get you going, but please update and improve your question, so that future readers can better understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

In general, a simple approach that should work is this: every time you get or check your position, calculate distance to the destination and if it's increased since the last time (which you need to keep track of), then display your alert. Since you added that this is for Android, you can do this as follows: Register a `LocationListener` in `requestLocationUpdates()`. Do the check for the distance check in the `onLocationChanged()` method of the `LocationListener`.